# как разрешить доступ к командам определенной роли или пользователям с правами администратора python discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_any_role('user')
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def clear(ctx, amount = 20):
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = amount)
```

Тут получается что доступ к команде получает пользователь с ролью user И правами администратора
Хочется как бы поставить or между @commands.has_any_role('user') и @commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_any_role('user') and commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=20):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

Кстати неплохо было бы следовать PEP8,
перед и после знака = не ставь пробелы , а также не нужен пробел перед limit

Comment: к сожаление такой метод как вы написали не работает. Он берет в оборот только то что написано первое. В этом и есть вопрос, мне бы хотелось чтобы( команду '!clear' мог писать пользователь с ролью 'role_name' или же любой другой с правами администратора )

Comment: работает , я проверял